# Delphi use CreateFile or WriteFile with 440bytes

Tags: delphi, winapi

Just look at the example below and please help me.

> if WriteFile(hDevice, bfile, 512, size, nil) then ShowMessage('Ok');

As above I use the 512, it worked, but with 440 as below, no.

> if WriteFile(hDevice, bfile, 440, size, nil) then ShowMessage('Ok');

My question, how can write a file size of 440 or less than 512 byte?

```
hDevice := CreateFile('\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1', GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if hDevice <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    begin
      bfile := CreateFile('C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\bfile', GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
      if bfile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
        begin
          ShowMessage(IntToStr(getlasterror));
          //SetFilePointer(hDevice,0,nil,FILE_BEGIN); // replace 0 with sector that you wish to read
          if WriteFile(hDevice, bfile, 440, size, nil) then ShowMessage('b');
          ShowMessage(IntToStr(getlasterror));
          CloseHandle(hDevice);
        end;
    end;
```

Comment: What does `GetLastError` return when the function fails?

Comment: @Tom Brunberg: It returns 2!

Comment: OK, and what does the docs say about 2?

Comment: @Tom Brunberg: ah I'm sorry, I was stuck and had forgotten the code revised

Comment: There is an error in code you have not shown. BTW, [error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) shows that 87 means **ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER**

Comment: Show more code, especially CreateFile call

Comment: If I use 512 instead of 440, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`WriteFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747.aspx) takes a pointer to a memory buffer as its second argument.

You are passing it a file handle instead.

Moreover, the destination is not an ordinary file, but a harddisk block device (which might have special limitations).

I assume you want to copy data from a file to some raw location on the block device. Solution: read the data from `bfile` into a memory buffer with `ReadFile()`, then pass that memory buffer to `WriteFile()` to write to `hDevice`.

If `WriteFile()` still refuses to accept 512 writes, either read the sector from `hDevice`, and copy the 440 bytes over the first bytes, or pad the 440 bytes with e.g. zeroes.

Of course, when used incorrectly, this code will mess up the boot sector of your harddisk (if Windows and the BIOS lets you), and since you don't seem to know what you are doing I hope for your sake that you are testing this only on a scratch system.

Comment: Thank you, I only try on a virtual machine and a virtual disk, it is safer

Comment: Thank you! The first method will not work for me, but the second method worked well.
I backed up 512 bytes of hard drive into a file `backup512`, then I overwrite 440 bytes of the file `bfile` to `backup512`, and then againt I write the file `backup512` to my hard drive

Comment: @ng Using a file as a temp buffer is weak. Use memory.

Comment: @David: Of course I will use better methods if I understand it and have done it. Probably in the future, but now is not. You did not give me an example so I need time to learn.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) says this:

> A volume contains one or more mounted file systems. Volume handles can
>   be opened as noncached at the discretion of the particular file
>   system, even when the noncached option is not specified in CreateFile.
>   You should assume that all Microsoft file systems open volume handles
>   as noncached. The restrictions on noncached I/O for files also apply
>   to volumes.
>
> A file system may or may not require buffer alignment even though the
>   data is noncached. However, if the noncached option is specified when
>   opening a volume, buffer alignment is enforced regardless of the file
>   system on the volume. It is recommended on all file systems that you
>   open volume handles as noncached, and follow the noncached I/O
>   restrictions.

One of the consequences of this is that you must read and write in multiples of the sector size. And all access must be on sector boundaries.

On top of that your code is badly broken at this point:

```
WriteFile(hDevice, bfile, 440, size, nil);
```

The second argument should be a pointer to a block of memory that is to be written to `hDevice`. You are instead supplying a file handle value. You presumably need to read from a file into a buffer, and then write that to the device.

This code would be a lot easier if you used streams. You can use a `TFileStream` to read from a file and `THandleStream` for writing to the device.

Comment: Thank you. I just learn about Delphi in recent days, are you willing to help me get full code from you???

Comment: That's not really how Stack Overflow works. We answer specific questions here rather than write code for people. Further, this is actually really a Windows issue and not a Delphi issue. Delphi just reflects the platform. What you need to know is that direct disk or volume access requires buffer alignment.

Comment: I'm a beginner, I can not read to understand the document without examples.

Comment: I tried as an example [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Copying_Data_Between_Streams), but it does not work on a hard drive.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to work. Why would you? I said THandleStream. The real point is the first part of my answer. Concerning buffer alignment. If you aren't interested in that and just want code then I'm the wrong person to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry
I'm not saying you're wrong, I just want to say that I will learn about what you mentioned at another time because I'm not qualified to understand.